# MongoDb Query returning unwanted documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a database containing documents of two structures:

```
{
  "name": "",
  "name_ar": "",
  "description": "",
  "bla1": {
    "name": "",
    "link": "",
    "Logo": ""
  },
  "bla2": {
    "name": "",
    "id": ""
  }
}
```

and

```
{
  "name": "",
  "name_ar": "",
  "description": "",
  "bla1": {
    "name": [],
    "link": "",
    "Logo": ""
  },
  "bla2": {
    "name": "",
    "id": ""
  }
}
```

I want to query my collection to get documents with "bla1.name" exactly equal to something. However using the following query:

```
{$and: [{'bla1.name': {'$type': 'string'}}, {"bla1.name":'something'}]}
```

returns all documents (even where "bla1.name" is an array) containing the name: 'something'.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why need to check `type`? Simply `db.collection.find({
  "bla1.name": "something"
})` should work.

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet that does not work as arrays containing the given value get selected, too.

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet that doesnt work if the array contains the name im looking for

Comment: @mbuechmann Oh yes!!! I had mistaken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the MongoDB docs:

> $type now works with arrays in the same way it works with other BSON types. Previous versions only matched documents where the field contained a nested array.

That means: If an array has at least one element with the given type it gets selected.

If you want to exclude arrays as type you have to extend your query. As the query already matches strings, you can exclude the type selection for string:

```
$and: [
  // not necessary any more, as this selection is already implied by the last part
  // {
  //   "bla1.name": {
  //     "$type": "string"
  //   }
  // },
  {
    "bla1.name": {
      $not: {
        "$type": "array"
      }
    }
  }, {
    "bla1.name": "something"
  }
]
```

See the official docs: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/#behavior

Here is a working demo on the Mongo playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/3ri7Bjfrae8